# Shared tomcat server for all components or separate instance individually?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee, architecture

This question is more from an architecture point of view. Do I need different instances and versions of tomcat server for my build automation server (Jenkins), messaging queue (Apache MQ) and for deploying my java web services/servlets? Or I can use just one and integrate all the components mentioned above with that one instance?

Comment: Please give valid reason if you gonna downvote this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can deploy multiple web applications on a single Apache Tomcat, you are able to deploy them all on one instance.
Whether this is a good idea depends on your needed and present resources and business rules.

Comment: Are you saying that I can have all these components on one machine? How do I configure different ports? Or same port will work for all of them?

Comment: The different applications on a single Apache Tomcat instance share the same TCP port, but are separated by context path which is part of the URL. `http://yourserver.local:8080/jenkins` for jenkins, `http://yourserver.local:8080/mq` for activeMq (if this is a deployable webApp at all), `http://yourserver.local:8080/webServiceXyz` for an application providing web services. If you are using this for build and test of your app, I'd consider this is ok.

Comment: If you want to use jenkins for development and build while using webservices + activeMq for actual production, I would suggest separating webService and activMq from jenkins as jenkins may heavily consume resources during build. Webservice must be responsive. @Emperor